# get current element parent then each element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get current element parent, then for each check the class here is my code:

```js
jQuery('input[name^="opt"]').click(function() {
  if (
    jQuery(this).hasClass('current_option') &&
    jQuery(this).is(':checked')
  ) {
    jQuery(this).prop('checked', false); 
    jQuery(this).removeClass('current_option');
    opConfig.reloadPrice();
  } else {
    var parents=jQuery(this).parent().parent();
    jQuery(parents +'li > input').each(function() {
      alert("445");
    });
    jQuery(this).addClass('current_option');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[1]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[1]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[1]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[1]" /><li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[2]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[2]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[2]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[2]" /><li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[3]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[3]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[3]" /><li>
  <li><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt[3]" /><li>
</ul>
```

This part of code is not working. I have to remove the class for current parent other elements.

```
var parents=jQuery(this).parent().parent();
jQuery(parents +'li > input').each(function() {
  alert("445");
});
```

Comment: What do you want? Add a class to UL parent of checked radio button and remove it of any other UL with this class?

Comment: Every radio that shares a common name will share only a single input, unless the brackets make an exception IDK.

Comment: I think you are looking `parents.siblings('ul').find('li > input')`

Comment: @zer00ne they are different with name `$opt[1]` like that. update the question

Comment: @Satpal  i will check and let you know

Comment: @A.Wolff i have remove class `current_option` for other option.

Comment: @QaisarSatti How will `('input[name^="options"]')` work if all of the radios are `name='opt[]'`? `$('input["name^=opt"]')` perhaps?

Comment: @zer00ne typo mistake this is not the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you explain why you used this part of snippet ?

```
var parents=jQuery(this).parent().parent();
jQuery(parents +'li > input').each(function() {
  alert("445");
});
```

If you explain little-bit then some one maybe give the right idea to best way to do it. and one more thing what really you want to do with your full of code ?

Anyway you can't get `li > input` by `parents` variable that you store by using `parent()` function.

why don't you try `find()` to this for you ?  like :

```
$(parents).find('input').each(function() {
  alert("445");
});
```